Do I also need ipv6 DNS in /etc/resolv.conf?
On RockyLinux 9.x, AlmaLinux 9.x, etc
I specify the nameservers to be added to /etc/resolv.conf by these 2 commands:
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.dns "8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 9.9.9.9"
nmcli con mod "System eth0" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes

The result:
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search tntcode.net
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 9.9.9.9

If server has both ipv4 and ipv6, it is not clear to me if in order for IPV6 connections to work properly, I also need to have an ipv6 DNS there ?

All DNS servers can give answers for all DNS queries. The method by which you send a DNS query doesn't restrict which record types you may query – both A and AAAA records can be queried over both IPv4 and IPv6 connections.

It is not mandatory to add entries for IPv6; in this case, the server will query DNS servers over the IPv4 protocol. However, it is considered a best practice and recommended to add IPv6 entries to /etc/resolv.conf as well.
